# Try to add a small delay when user says the word "Chrome" or "Google" (Speech Recognition)

Tags: javascript, speech-recognition

I'm working on a Speech Recognition and I have got the basics down to make it work when I say a command it runs it but I have interimResults set to true so when I say for it to open google it will open the link before I can add what I want it to search.

if you don't really understand what I am saying do say and I will try and explain better.

this is my code.

```
// tables
const keywordFacts = {
    "startLetters": "o",
    "endLetters": "n",
    "minLetters": 3,
    "maxLetters": 4,
}

const commandTable = {
    "gmail": () => window.open('https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/'),
    "youtube": () => window.open('https://youtube.com'),
    "calculator": () => window.open('https://www.google.com/search?q=google+calculator'),
    "google": (query) => window.open(`https://www.google.com/search?q=${query}`),
    "chrome": (query) => window.open(`https://www.google.com/search?q=${query}`),
}

// values
let commandExecuted = false;

// functions
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const userText = document.getElementById('userText');
    const speechRecognition = window.speechRecognition || window.webkitSpeechRecognition;
    const recognition = new speechRecognition();

    recognition.lang = 'en';
    recognition.continuous = true;
    recognition.interimResults = true;

    recognition.start();

    recognition.onresult = (event) => {
        const last = event.results.length - 1;
        const text = event.results[last][0].transcript;
        const lowerCaseText = text.toLowerCase();
        const finalText = lowerCaseText.split(" ");
    
        userText.textContent = text;
    
        if (event.results[last].isFinal) {
            for (let i = 0; i < finalText.length; i++) {
                const word = finalText[i];
                const isKeywordValid = (
                    word.startsWith(keywordFacts.startLetters) &&
                    word.endsWith(keywordFacts.endLetters) &&
                    word.length >= keywordFacts.minLetters &&
                    word.length <= keywordFacts.maxLetters
                );
    
                if (isKeywordValid) {
                    const nextWord = finalText[i + 1];
                    const isCommandPresent = Object.keys(commandTable).some(command => nextWord && nextWord.toLowerCase().includes(command));
    
                    if (isCommandPresent && !commandExecuted) {
                        const matchingCommand = Object.keys(commandTable).find(command => nextWord.toLowerCase().includes(command));
                        if (matchingCommand) {
                            const query = finalText.slice(i + 2).join(" ");
                            commandTable[matchingCommand](query);
                            commandState();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    recognition.onerror = (event) => {
        userText.textContent = "I'm sorry I didn't quite get that";
    }
});

async function commandState() {
    commandExecuted = true;
    await wait(2)
    commandExecuted = false;
}

async function wait(time) {return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time*1000));}
```

I have tried looking on google and using a if statement to check if the word is "Chrome" or "Google" and add a little wait to check for when the user stops talking but I couldn't get it to work.